# When is a cellular automaton "bidirectional"?

Tags: cellular-automata

From [this paper](http://xn--80afqipfk7a.xn--p1ai/2005/proceedings/papers/VezhntvetsKonushin.pdf).

"A (bi-directional, deterministic) cellular automaton is a triplet
$A = (S;N;\delta)$, where $S$ is an non-empty state set, $N$ is the neighborhood system, and $\delta$ is the local transition function (rule).
This function deﬁnes the rule of calculating the cell’s state at $t +1$
time step, given the states of the neighborhood cells at previous
time step $t$"

I haven't found other "bidirectional" CA via Google, so I wonder what does the term say about this automaton's properties. Does it mean that the state $t+1$ can be used to find out the state $t$?